# How to keep mouse coordinates within window height/width limits

Tags: opengl, glfw

Suppose I have a 600 by 600 window created through `glfwCreateWindow()`.

I have a few models rendered in the scene and to move around them in the 3D space I use a camera class which moves around with my cursor as well as AWSD/spacebar keys.

To make the movement "seamless" I use `glfwSetInputMode(this->window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED)`.

Now then the problem is that I am also trying to implent a mouse picker of sorts (casting ray from cursor position to the scene).

So I implemented the mouse picker from a video I found on yt, but it doesnt work properly. The reason being is that my mouse X and Y coordinates get bigger than width and height if for example I rotate on spot (and I can increase it this way indefinitely).

I understand that this is happening because I have no cursor to be bound within resolution limits due to `glfwSetInputMode(this->window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED)`. I am asking how I should correct this so that I can keep the seamlessness as well as be able to limit the cursor coordinates within width and height (otherwise the mouse picker function wont work because normalized mouse coordinates go over [1,1] which completely breaks it and so on).

I will be grateful for any answers.

**EDIT:**

@httpdigest's answer put into very elementary code:

```
        //store offsetX and offsetY values (and dont forget to give them 0 as initial value)
        overshootX = mouseX - offsetX;
        overshootY = mouseY - offsetY;

        if (overshootX > width) {
            offsetX = offsetX + overshootX - width;
        }
        if (overshootX < 0) {
            offsetX = offsetX + overshootX;
        }
        if (overshootY > height) {
            offsetY = offsetY + overshootY - height;
        }
        if (overshootY < 0) {
            offsetY = offsetY + overshootY;
        }

        float withinWindowCursorPosX = mouseX - offsetX;
        float withinWindowCursorPosY = mouseY - offsetY;
```

Comment: I see glfwSetCursorPos(GLFWWindow*, int xpos, int ypos) in the api. 
Given you have this, and can get the position in the mousecallback, I think you should be able to limit it with that? Haven't actually tried it, but just a thought. 

Effectively implementing clamp for mouse coordinates. 

Another thought is potentially storing the offset into separate state, and only adding to the offset when the old mouse position was within the bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it is to store an `offset` (initially `(0, 0)`) by how much the cursor moved beyond the bounds of the window/viewport (separate for X and Y).

Essentially, everytime when you either read the current cursor position or are being told of an update by an event, you calculate `overshoot = cursorPos - offset` (separate for X and Y). If `overshoot` exceeds `(width, height)` you increment `offset` by the excess it exceeded `(width, height)`. Likewise, if `overshoot` is less than `(0, 0)` you decrement `offset` by the negative overshoot.

That way, you have a "sliding" window/rectangle which gets slided around as you keep on moving the mouse cursor beyond either edge of the screen.

Now, whenever you want to obtain the corrected cursor position (within your window), you simply use `withinWindowCursorPos = cursorPos - offset`.

You can then use `withinWindowCursorPos` for your picking calculations that require a cursor within the window/viewport.

Comment: Hey there man, I am a little lost. I understand how this would solve my issue and Im trying to translate it into code it but it just wont work as intended.

Comment: Ive edited the question with the code Im working on based off of your answer, if you could take a look Id be grateful.